# Magento 2 add new Button in admin Controller

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, controllers, custom-button

I am working on module which will work for sync product from Third party Api.I have already created admin controller page but don't have Idea how to add button **Sync Products** whose action will call a controller file .
Have anyone idea how to add new custom button with action controller?

I have added menu in admin section with Parent Catalog->

Admin menu is

> **app/code/Vendorname/Syncfromshopify/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendorname_Syncfromshopify::sync_product" title="Sync From Shopiofy" module="Vendorname_Syncfromshopify" parent="Magento_Catalog::catalog" sortOrder="30"  resource="Vendorname_Syncfromshopify::sync_product" action="syncproductshopify/syncproduct/" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

My controller is

> **app/code/Vendorname/Syncfromshopify/Controller/Adminhtml/Syncproduct/Index.php**

```
namespace Vendorname\Syncfromshopify\Controller\Adminhtml\Syncproduct;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\ResultPageFactory;


class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action

{
    /**
    * @var PageFactory
    */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

My above controller is working fine and redirecting to admin page.

Now I want to add a button (ABC name) and in action of another controller which will responsible for sync data from third party and Insert in Magento.

So How we will create new button in admin controller and give action?

Comment: What is your Magento version?

Comment: Magento version 2.2.1

Comment: But, you want to add the button on product listing page or edit form?

Comment: I want to add button in custom module,just in an controller.

Comment: Please guide me how to add button in admin controller file and what we will require for it.

Comment: Your question made me confused. Please edit it and give us more details.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Where is your Block? Did you declare the Block?

Comment: yes,I have declare the block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70483/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-akgola).

Comment: Ok thanks,Please let me know when you will available

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in Vendorname\Module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomButtom.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Buttom;

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface;

class CustomButtom extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container {
    protected $_backendUrl;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        UrlInterface $backendUrl,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_backendUrl = $backendUrl;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Block constructor adds buttons
     *
     */
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->addButton(
            'import_ref',
            $this->getButtonData()
        );
        parent::_construct();
    }

    /**
     * Return button attributes array
     */
    public function getButtonData() {
        $url = $this->_backendUrl->getUrl("module/page/index");
        return [
            'label' => __('Custom buttom label'),
            'on_click' => 'setLocation("'.$url.'")',
            'class' => 'primary'
        ];
    }
}
```

In your layout just need to add the buttom

Vendorname\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\name-layout.xml

```
<block class="Vendorname\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Status\CustomButtom" name="CustomButtom"/>
```